# BLOB image to iOS app thru PHP:

Tags: php, ios, image, request, blob

I have an image stored as a blob in an MySQL database. Now I want to get this image over to my iOS app so that I could present it on the app.

1. How to use the blob in the PHP and how to return it when a request is made?
2. What code should I use to fetch the picture from the server?

Any example / tutorial / answer would really help, so thanks in advanced!

Comment: why would one store images inside a mysql database?

Comment: store the link in the database and upload the image on the file-server?

Comment: Would that still be efficient if I store a profile picture for every user, and have thousands of users on my website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch blob content from mysql table and then do base64_encode. pass encoded image data to your iOS app and then decode at iOS level